# GStreamer-based video player without many non-LXDE dependencies?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-player, gstreamer, lxde

I want to use a GStreamer-based video player, preferably using a GTK frontend, on LXDE. I'm afraid Totem could possibly bring in a lot of GNOME dependencies, hence seeking alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could try [Parole](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/parole) which actually is media player of xfce so will install xfce dependencies.

[image]

Or you could try [xnoise](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/06/xnoise-new-lightweight-linux-music.html) which is said to support gstreamer but xnoise seems much more oriented towards music than videos but it can play videos according to its review on the above link.

Can be installed from ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shkn/xnoise && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xnoise
```

Comment: Isn't has dependency-heavy as Totem, but still a lot of XFCE dependencies on Parole. :(